# converting antd table data into hooks

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, object, react-hooks

React beginner here, i'm currently learning Reactjs, since everybody is saying React hooks is easier to start with, so i started with hooks, but everywhere is mainly react with classes, here in this example (antd table) it is coded using classes, if i have understood it currently, i should put 'searchText:'',searchedColumn:'',' into useState, and dont need useEffect ? since there is no componentdimount or udpate .. ? just for learning want to change this class code into Hooks, sory for mistakes because english is not my mother language:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import './index.css';
import { Table, Input, Button, Space } from 'antd';
import Highlighter from 'react-highlight-words';
import { SearchOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';

const data = [
  {
    key: '1',
    name: 'John Brown',
    age: 32,
    address: 'New York No. 1 Lake Park',
  },
  {
    key: '2',
    name: 'Joe Black',
    age: 42,
    address: 'London No. 1 Lake Park',
  },
  {
    key: '3',
    name: 'Jim Green',
    age: 32,
    address: 'Sidney No. 1 Lake Park',
  },
  {
    key: '4',
    name: 'Jim Red',
    age: 32,
    address: 'London No. 2 Lake Park',
  },
];

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    searchText: '',
    searchedColumn: '',
  };

  getColumnSearchProps = dataIndex => ({
    filterDropdown: ({ setSelectedKeys, selectedKeys, confirm, clearFilters }) => (
      <div style={{ padding: 8 }}>
        <Input
          ref={node => {
            this.searchInput = node;
          }}
          placeholder={`Search ${dataIndex}`}
          value={selectedKeys[0]}
          onChange={e => setSelectedKeys(e.target.value ? [e.target.value] : [])}
          onPressEnter={() => this.handleSearch(selectedKeys, confirm, dataIndex)}
          style={{ width: 188, marginBottom: 8, display: 'block' }}
        />
        <Space>
          <Button
            type="primary"
            onClick={() => this.handleSearch(selectedKeys, confirm, dataIndex)}
            icon={<SearchOutlined />}
            size="small"
            style={{ width: 90 }}
          >
            Search
          </Button>
          <Button onClick={() => this.handleReset(clearFilters)} size="small" style={{ width: 90 }}>
            Reset
          </Button>
          <Button
            type="link"
            size="small"
            onClick={() => {
              confirm({ closeDropdown: false });
              this.setState({
                searchText: selectedKeys[0],
                searchedColumn: dataIndex,
              });
            }}
          >
            Filter
          </Button>
        </Space>
      </div>
    ),
    filterIcon: filtered => <SearchOutlined style={{ color: filtered ? '#1890ff' : undefined }} />,
    onFilter: (value, record) =>
      record[dataIndex]
        ? record[dataIndex].toString().toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())
        : '',
    onFilterDropdownVisibleChange: visible => {
      if (visible) {
        setTimeout(() => this.searchInput.select(), 100);
      }
    },
    render: text =>
      this.state.searchedColumn === dataIndex ? (
        <Highlighter
          highlightStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#ffc069', padding: 0 }}
          searchWords={[this.state.searchText]}
          autoEscape
          textToHighlight={text ? text.toString() : ''}
        />
      ) : (
        text
      ),
  });

  handleSearch = (selectedKeys, confirm, dataIndex) => {
    confirm();
    this.setState({
      searchText: selectedKeys[0],
      searchedColumn: dataIndex,
    });
  };

  handleReset = clearFilters => {
    clearFilters();
    this.setState({ searchText: '' });
  };

  render() {
    const columns = [
      {
        title: 'Name',
        dataIndex: 'name',
        key: 'name',
        width: '30%',
        ...this.getColumnSearchProps('name'),
      },
      {
        title: 'Age',
        dataIndex: 'age',
        key: 'age',
        width: '20%',
        ...this.getColumnSearchProps('age'),
      },
      {
        title: 'Address',
        dataIndex: 'address',
        key: 'address',
        ...this.getColumnSearchProps('address'),
      },
    ];
    return <Table columns={columns} dataSource={data} />;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Code can also be found here: https://codesandbox.io/s/lq2it?file=/package.json

Comment: I don't see any lifecycle methods except `render()` here so no, I don't think you need to have `useEffect` anywhere here. If you had something like `componentDidMount()` then some of that code in there would go into the `useEffect()` hook. Finally, yes, you should use useState() hook for `searchText` and `searchColumn`

Comment: @andromeda could you possibly write working code, so that everybody can learn, since there is no react hooks version of antd tables ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `searchText` and `searchedColumn` are states and should be declared with `useState` like so:

```
const [searchText, updateSearchText] = useState('default_state');
const [searchedColumn, updateSearchedColumn] = useState('default_state');
```

`updateSearchText(some_value)` is the equivalent for

```
this.setState({
searchText : some_value
})
```

and `updateSearchedColumn` is the same said above but for the state: `searchedColumn`

Comment: thats good that i'm on right way, could you possible correct the code and write working code, so that everybody can learn,  since there is no react hooks version of antd tables ?

Comment: Hey @waleedd32, this is not how it works here. But let me give you an advice: if you are well known with React **classes**, then work with React classes and not with functional components and hooks... :)